# plugin c# in crm dynamics: plugin trigger workflow when after set period of time

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365

I am creating a plugin in dynamics 365, the aim is when the incident entity statuscode is set to 1 or 3 then a workflow is triggered. However, the statuscode must be set to 1 or 3 for a period of 24 hours before the workflow is triggered.
Also after the workflow is executed the statuscode should be set to pending.

I am unsure if I am going in the right direction to code this. I am unsure how to do this. If someone can show me how to solve this scenario. Thanks!

This is what I have so far: For testing purposes the time period to trigger the workflow is 10 seconds.

```
public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
  ITracingService tracingService = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));
  IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
  IOrganizationServiceFactory factory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
  IOrganizationService service = factory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

  //create an entity
  Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

  //after creating the entity, we need to retrieve the required entity: Incident
  //retrieve incident entity
  Incident detail = entity.ToEntity<Incident>();

  //contain int value that represents the optionset
  TimeSpan sec = new TimeSpan(00,00,10);

  // var incident = service.Retrieve("incident", detail.IncidentId.Value, new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query.ColumnSet(true)).ToEntity<Incident>();
  //retrieve the value of status code of a particular entity
  //if optionsetvalue is the same for a 24 hr period

  if (detail.StatusCode== new OptionSetValue(1) || detail.StatusCode == new OptionSetValue(3))
  {
    if (sec != null)
    {
      ExecuteWorkflowRequest request = new ExecuteWorkflowRequest()
      {
          WorkflowId = new Guid("DB9ABA7E-D4F9-4EBF-8062-C85EF7B850FB"),
          EntityId = detail.Id,
      };
      ExecuteWorkflowResponse response = (ExecuteWorkflowResponse)service.Execute(request);

      //change it to pending..statuscode
      detail.StatusCode = new OptionSetValue(425390002);
    }

    service.Update(detail);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Plugin is not advised to use in this scenario. You have to use UI Workflow to do this. There is a [Timeout](http://blog.clickdimensions.com/crm-workflows-wait-versus-timeout/) option to wait until & do the needed step later on.

Something like this:

[image]

Even you can execute the needed WF as child workflow from this WF.